# How can I fix button disabling while trying to use innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, blogs, innerhtml

I'm trying to use inner HTML JS to create a blog so that when a button is clicked, the rest of the content is revealed to the user. I've tried using this code to make it work, and code just like it have worked for other projects, but for some reason, it disables the button and it does not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my Code (I am certain that I have imported each respective file correctly as I made this on glitch)

```js
var secret = document.getElementById("secret");
var readMore = document.getElementById("sth");
readMore.addEventListener("click", shareSecret);

function shareSecret() {
  secret.innerHTML =
    "The truth? There is no secret to happiness. We are all doomed to die a miserable death and live a life with depression before doing so. If anyone knows how to be happy, it sure isn't me.";
}
```

```html
<div class="morecontent">
  <p id="secret">
    Click the button below to see the secret...
  </p>
</div>
<button id="sth">Read More</button>
```

Comment: I see no problem here, reproduced and still be able to click `Read More`

Comment: After the button is clicked, the innerHTML of `secret` element is set, and would not change after clicking button again. The button is not disabling, it is just that, the changes are not visible as the content is not changing after one click.

Answer (score 0):

Add `readMore.disabled=true;` in your shareSecret() function.

EDIT: it is a good idea to display none if the button is of no use in future after click by adding `readMore.style.display = 'none';`

```js
var secret = document.getElementById("secret");
var readMore = document.getElementById("sth");
readMore.addEventListener("click", shareSecret);

function shareSecret() {
  secret.innerHTML ="The truth? There is no secret to happiness. We are all doomed to die a miserable death and live a life with depression before doing so. If anyone knows how to be happy, it sure isn't me.";
  readMore.disabled=true;

}
```

```html
<div class="morecontent">
  <p id="secret">
    Click the button below to see the secret...
  </p>
</div>
<button id="sth">Read More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in your snippet is correct. If it don't work in your project check the syntax, you can omit some letter or something like that.
If the button disable add:

```
readmore.removeAttribute("disabled");
```